Joining Two Objects Together W/Geo Nodes (Scalable)
I need help figuring out how to merge between two objects generated using geo nodes, one is a blade of grass that is 5 vertices wide and the other object is a spiral that is only 5 vertices in resolution, how can I interpolate or merge the top of the spiral into the bottom of the grass blade that is scalable?(being able to change 5 to whatever number)




Given your grass has the starting indices 0 to 4 at the bottom (good), we can make the spiral extruded "up" select the top of the spiral and set the positions based on index:

This setup works ok if you extrude the spiral up.

Thanks, this seems to work fairly well.
